# Как реализовать наведение на картинку с затемнением фона и появлением иконки-ссылке

Tags: css3, html5

Я верстаю на bootstrap 4. Как сделать, чтобы при наведении на картинку, она затемнялась и появлялся значок-ссылка (картинка png) с белым задним фоном?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Пример

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.pict{
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: url(https://placeimg.com/640/480/arch) no-repeat center top / cover;
}
.pict:before{
    content: '';
    top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.75);
}
.pict:after{
    content: 'i';
    top: 50%; left: 50%;
    margin: -20px 0 0 -20px;
    width: 40px; 
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #000;
    background: #fff;
    
}
.pict:before,
.pict:after{
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .3s ease;
}
.pict:hover:before,
.pict:hover:after{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="pict"></div>
```